# Automatically combining a set of PDF files

Tags: header-footer, conversion

Say I have a bunch of Word documents, PowerPoint and Excel files. I have some cover photo.

I want to convert the files to PDF, add the cover photo and footer to the bottom of each page `hello world`

Could it be automated in LaTeX? I want to run it on a Windows server.

I can convert the files to PDF using a Python script.  I guess I can do everything using Python but I don't trust Python for more than conversion, manipulating files is better done in LaTeX I guess.

Comment: What footnotes? In general, you can use the `pdfpages` package to include existing PDFs into a LaTeX document, but LaTeX cannot directly read Word files, let alone Powerpoint or Excel.

Comment: (Caveat lector: I know nothing about Windows servers, and virtually nothing about Windows.) If you can batch convert the files to PDF, then it would be fairly easy to do this with `pdfpages`.  If you want to convert the `.doc(x)` files to `.tex` files on the fly, then probably not.  I'd also export the Excel files to `.csv` and use something like `datatool`.  I assume PowerPoint cannot be converted to a `.tex` file at all, however.

Comment: You can export a `.ppt` to `.pdf`, though, and include the images - again with `pdfpages`. Why do you want to do this in LaTeX?

Comment: @jon I'm not sure it would be easy to add the footnotes, though. Would need to know a lot more about the set-up. (Are the footnotes the same for every page? Do all exported PDFs have sufficient room for them at the bottom of each page? Etc.)

Comment: @cfr -- Good point.  I guess I assumed the 'footnotes' would be a footer, which would be much easier obviously.

Comment: @jon True. But you still need sufficient room. Does Word still feature relatively small margins by default? (I haven't used Word much for ages. And I haven't created a document from scratch in Word since... er... for over a decade.)

Comment: @cfr -- I'm not sure.  I always assumed the 1" or 2.5 cm margins often insisted upon by others represented the general defaults of word processing software..?  I figured that, in a worst case scenario, you either scale the inclusion or simply overwrite. Ideally, there'd be room enough, or you use `geometry` to put the header/footer in the right place.

Comment: @cfr please read my edit

Comment: OK. Yes. So use @jon's suggestion, then.

Comment: The basic idea is: (1) Create a `masterfile.tex` which loads the packages (including package `pdfpages`), sets the layout (e.g., the footer); (2) between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, add one line: `\input{content}`; (3) whatever process you have that generates the PDF should also write a file `content.tex` with lines like `\includepdf[<options>]{file01.pdf}` corresponding to the converted files. Perhaps also something like an `\addcontentsline` for each included file to put things in the table of contents. But it depends some on how you are generating the PDFs.

Comment: @Johannes_B nope, I abandoned the project after not being able to add footers using python or latex

Comment: So the question can be closed and removed from the list of unanswered questions?

Comment: @Johannes_B is this a new policy on this site? closing unanswered questions just because they are unanswered? never heard of it before, what if someone came up with a solution next year? anyhow, if you want to close it, it's okay with me, I'm just against the reason behind it. I'm not against closing this particualar question, unless someone comes up with a solution, this question is dead. But what good would closing a question do? that's my question. Makes the stats on this site looks good? that's all?

Comment: As it stands the question is not very clear and asks if it can be done. Please improve the question.

Comment: @Johannes_B no need you can close it, if you want, can't see how to improve this question. again im not against closing this particular question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say that you can covert all the different file types to PDF, then doing what you want isn't very difficult using the `pdfpages` package. As others have noted in the comments, there may be issues of margins in the source document not being sufficient for the footer, but I should think that these are solvable problems.

Here's a basic method to do this.  I've made some simplifying assumptions about how your files are named, which allows the code to be inserted with a loop. If you need filenames to be more distinct from one another, you could use your python script to generate the whole latex document itself if needed.  Alternatively you could store the filenames in a CSV file and use the `datatool` package to generate the document insertion loop.

Here's a simple example.  It assumes that you have named each PDF file `File1.pdf`, `File2.pdf`,..., `File*n*.pdf`.

The document then adds a title page (with an image), and loops through inserting each file and adding a distinctive footer line with a rule and page number.  I've made the document margins small to reduce the chances that the added footer will overlap with any existing footer in the documents.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=.75in,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newpagestyle{main}{%
\setfootrule{3pt}
\setfoot{\itshape\sffamily My Footer Line}{}{\sffamily\itshape\thepage}}
\pagestyle{main}
\def\filecount{3} % change this to match the number of files
\title{My Bunch of Documents}
\author{My Name}
\date{}
% add image to titlepage using the titling package + graphicx
\postdate{\par\vfil\includegraphics{cow}\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\foreach \x in {1,...,\filecount}{
\includepdf[pages=1-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{main}}]{File\x}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Johannes_B our little argument brought this question to light!